# Unable to paste in VIM

Tags: vim, pasting

Steps to reproduce:

1) Open any file (example.txt).

2) Press v and select some lines.

3) Press y to yank them (also tried yy).

4) :q to quit.

5) Open any other file.

6) p to paste.

7) E353: Nothing in register "

Comment: This is a pretty good question, I finally landed here to solve my problem, while the top listed question from Google Search actually didn't get the point. Question and answers here are super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use system's clipboard when pasting between separate vim instances. Try `"+y` to copy to the `+` register and `"+p` to paste from it. Depending on your OS, you might also try the `*` register if `+` does not seem to work.

Comment: Am I doing this right, I just select the text, then "+y while in visual mode?  If So I get the same error when trying to paste.

Comment: Are you pasting from the register too? "+p otherwise you'll just paste from the default register. Try typing the command :reg to see what is in each available register. Also try "*p and compare.

Comment: BTW I highly recommend http://vim-adventures.com . You don't get to registers until about level 10, but it's great for getting to grips with Vim fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

Yank/paste buffer is not saved between runs of vim, at least by default. Instead do: y, then :split other-file, and paste it there.

Comment: It is. Not by default, but it is. See `:h 'viminfo'`, you need `"` suboption.